# Why can't I set top and left to $(window).width() * number

Tags: html, css

In my css file, I set

```
#background_layer0{
   width: $(window).width();
   height: $(window).height();
}
```

And it works. However, As I set

```
#background_layer0{
   top: $(window).width() * 0.5;
   left: $(window).height() * 0.6;
}
```

It can't work. I can't see any differences between this two kind of attribute:

 `width , height` and `top left`.
Please correct my fault and explain why. Also, I hope you can give me some reference to read.

UPDATE: I need to deploy the webpage to another device like: cellphone. 
If I only use percentage as value, can it work?

Comment: You can't use JavaScript in a CSS file. How exactly do you get the first example to work?

Comment: do this by `.css()` function

Comment: Well... Why does the first one work... How can I set the element size to fix the screen width and height in CSS file...

Comment: I suspect that if you really have that in the CSS file it works because it resets to default (100%) when you give an invalid value.

Comment: @Juhana        Yes, I checked it. You are right. Should I have to write another separate js file to get connection between the element and the body?

Comment: No. Use percentages as the answers show.

Comment: Using percentages results in something different. `$(window).height()` is not the same as `$(document).height()`, which should be equal to the body height and the 100% value

Comment: The only way using javascript in "css" would be by using less (and/or sass?), but even then you cannot use jQuery: [http://lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation)

Comment: @KilianStinson  Why is that? Can you explain it?

Comment: `$(window).height()` is the height of your browsers viewport. `$(document).height()` is the height of your html document. See this question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504195/what-is-the-difference-between-document-height-and-window-height?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate JavaScript file or include this in a script tag

```
$('#background_layer0').css('top', function() {
    return $(window).width() * 0.5;
});

$('#background_layer0').css('left', function() {
    return $(window).height() * 0.6;
});
```

Comment: as Juhana has said, you do not need the anonymous function within this code. just use `$('#background_layer0').css('top', $(window).width() * 0.5);`

Comment: As soon as I have to calculate something, I prefer the anonymous function for its better readability. Though this example is still quite simple.

Comment: Wait, you forgot `)` after the anonymous function~ Please update.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use percentage:

```
#background_layer0{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#background_layer0{
top: 50%;
left: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Why the anonymous functions? `.css('left', $(window).height() * 0.6)` would work just as well.

Comment: `height: 100%` as child of the body element, is not the same as `$(window).height()`

Answer (score 0):

So, in CSS, you cannot use `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()`, you must specify it in percent, pixels, etc. (it must be absolute)

To make an object's width same with the window width and height, you must use javascript/jquery