# what does $('body').height() returns here?

Tags: jquery

I am looking at the code written by someone else. In this a class is added of removed when we reach a particular section.I cannot understand the use of $('body').height() here

```
if($('#impact_calculator'). length){
        $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        // var box = $('#impact_calculator').offset().top -190;
        var box = $('body').height() - $('#impact_calculator').height() - 450;
        if (scroll >= box) {
            setTimeout(() => {
            $("body").addClass("sticky");
            }, 500);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("body").removeClass("sticky");
            }, 500);
        }

    });
```

Comment: The window is the visible viewport of your device, think of your smartphone. The body can be much larger. That's why you sometimes see scrollbars.

Comment: Please search before posting a new question. Searching for your exact title turns up many answers here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504195/what-is-the-difference-between-document-height-and-window-height, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035819/window-height-vs-document-height, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023183/jquery-body-height-returns-undefined, ...

Comment: I know the difference between window and document height , i was confused with the keyword body. Is  $("body").height()  same as  $("document").height() ?  this was my main confusion

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to this link for your reference: https://api.jquery.com/height/

```
// Returns height of browser viewport
$(window).height();
```

Usually, `$(window).height()` delivers the browser window's height less one pixel. The height of the current browser window is always this. This value do need to alter as your browser is resized.

```
// Returns height of HTML document
$(document).height();
```

`$(document).height()` returns an unit-less pixel value of the height of the document being rendered.